# How should I correctly join two tables so that I can access a property in one of the entities?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web API using EntityFramework. EntityFramework is built as a separate project. In the API, I have the following model:

```
namespace Web_API.Models
{
    [Table("SomeFiles")]
    public class SomeFilesViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public int PatchNumber{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the EF, I have the following entities:

```
namespace SomeDataAccess
{
    public partial class Patch
    {
        public int PatchID { get; set; }
        public double Number { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PatchFile
    {
        public int FileID { get; set; }
        public int PatchID{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I implement a GET method using LINQ to return the list of files between two `Patch` Numbers (Not patch ids)? Below is what I have thus far but "Number" is not listed as property of files even though I have joined it.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSomeFileViewModels(double StartingPatch, double EndingPatch)
{
    var files = from pf in _context.PatchFiles
                join p in _context.Patches on pf.PatchID equals p.PatchID
                select pf;

    var patchFiles = await files.Where(i => i.Number(???) >= StartingPatch & i.Number <= EndingPatch)
                                .Select(someFiles => new SomeFileViewModel
                                {
                                    FileId = files.FileID,
                                    PatchNumber = (???),
                                    Name = files.Name,
                                    Type = files.Type,
                                }).ToListAsync();

    return !patchFiles.Any()
           ? (IHttpActionResult)NotFound()
           : Ok(patchFiles);
}
```

Comment: OK. Could you show, what have you tried?

Comment: @S.Akbari I have updated my post. I am not sure how to correctly join the two tables so that I can have access to Number in Patch entity?

Comment: To make this easier, your model should have Navigation Properties.  Eg PatchFile should have a property `public virtual Patch Patch {get;set;}`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Can you please provide a solution with the navigation property? Or can you provide me a link that explains this?

Comment: With a Navigation Property you can simply query across to the related entity `files.Where(i => i.Patch.Number >= StartingPatch . . . `

Comment: This worked too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your `Select` statement. Currently you have just retrieved the `pf` which is `PatchFiles`. You can select an anonymous type with your select statement like this:

```
select new { PatchFile = pf, Patch = p};
```

You query should be something like this now:

```
var files = (from pf in _context.PatchFiles
             join p in _context.Patches on pf.PatchID equals p.PatchID
             select new { PatchFile = pf, Patch = p}).ToList();
```

Then you can:

```
files.Where(i => i.Patche.Number)
```